# How to fix Usage error in strftime in Perl script

Tags: perl, pdf, strftime

I am writing Perl script signature.pl to build PDF Dictionary and Signature dictionary objects
This has the PEM and PDF in variables declared. I have used POSIX for strftime

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use PDF::API2;
use PDF::API2::Basic::PDF::Utils;
use File::Slurp;
use POSIX;

use Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA;
use Crypt::OpenSSL::X509 qw/FORMAT_UNDEF FORMAT_ASN1 FORMAT_TEXT FORMAT_PEM/;
use Digest::SHA1 qw(sha1 sha1_hex);

my $add_mdp = 0;
my $input_filename = "signature.pdf";
my $tempfilename   = 'tmp.pdf';
my $outfilename    = 'tmp.pdf';

my $sig_algorithm  = 'pkcs7';
my $sig_length     = 20480;

my $cacert_filename   = "signature.pem";
my $x509_filename     = "signature.pem";
my $priv_key_filename = "signature.pem";

my $cacert   = Crypt::OpenSSL::X509->new_from_file($cacert_filename);
my $x509     = Crypt::OpenSSL::X509->new_from_file($x509_filename);
my $priv_key = read_file($priv_key_filename);

my $timestamp  = localtime;
my $tz         = POSIX::strftime("%z", $timestamp);
$tz            =~ s/([\+\-])(\d\d)(\d\d)/$1$2'$3'/;
my $timestring = POSIX::strftime("D:%Y%m%d%H%M%S$tz", $timestamp);

my $location   = `hostname`;
chomp $location;

my $contact_info = PDFStr($x509->email());

my $signer_name  = PDFStr($x509->subject_name->as_string);

my $pdf = PDF::API2->open($input_filename);
my $p   = $pdf->{catalog}->{' parent'};

my $sigdict             = PDF::API2::Basic::PDF::Dict->new();
$sigdict->{Type}        = PDFName("Sig");
$sigdict->{Filter}      = PDFName("Adobe.PPKLite");
$sigdict->{Reason}      = PDFStr("Testing my PDF Signature Demo Tool");
$sigdict->{Name}        = $signer_name;
$sigdict->{ContactInfo} = $contact_info;
$sigdict->{Location}    = $location;
$sigdict->{M}           = $timestring;

if ($sig_algorithm eq 'rsa') {
    $sigdict->{SubFilter} = PDFName('adbe.x509.rsa.sha1');
    my @certs;
    push @certs, PDFStr $x509->as_string(FORMAT_ASN1);
    push @certs, PDFStr $cacert->as_string(FORMAT_ASN1);
    $sigdict->{Cert}      = PDFArray @certs if ($sig_algorithm eq 'rsa');
} else {
    $sigdict->{SubFilter} = PDFName('adbe.pkcs7.detached');
}

$sigdict->{Contents}  = PDFStrHex("\0" x $sig_length);
$sigdict->{ByteRange} = PDF::API2::Basic::PDF::Literal->new("[0 00000000 00000000 00000000]");

if ($add_mdp) {
    my $sigrefdict                 = PDF::API2::Basic::PDF::Dict->new();
    $sigrefdict->{Type}            = PDFName("SigRef");
    $sigrefdict->{TransformMethod} = PDFName("DocMDP");
    $sigrefdict                    = $p->new_obj($sigrefdict);
    $sigdict->{Reference}          = PDFArray($sigrefdict);
}

$sigdict = $p->new_obj($sigdict);

my $sigannotdict         = PDF::API2::Basic::PDF::Dict->new();
my $sigformdict          = PDF::API2::Basic::PDF::Dict->new();

$sigannotdict->{Type}    = PDFName("Annot");
$sigannotdict->{Subtype} = PDFName("Widget");
$sigannotdict->{F}       = PDFNum(4);
$sigannotdict->{Parent}  = $sigformdict;
$sigannotdict->{Rect}    = PDF::API2::Basic::PDF::Literal->new("[0 0 0 0]");
$sigannotdict->{P}       = $pdf->openpage(1);
$sigannotdict->{H}       = PDFName("N");
$sigannotdict            = $p->new_obj($sigannotdict);

$sigformdict->{FT}       = PDFName("Sig");
$sigformdict->{T}        = PDFStr("Demo Signature");
$sigformdict->{V}        = $sigdict;
$sigformdict->{Kids}     = PDFArray($sigannotdict);
$sigformdict             = $p->new_obj($sigformdict);

if ($add_mdp) {
    my $permdict              = PDF::API2::Basic::PDF::Dict->new();
    $permdict->{DocMDP}       = $sigdict;
    $permdict                 = $p->new_obj($permdict);
    $pdf->{catalog}->{'Perm'} = $permdict;
}

my @formarray;
push @formarray, $sigformdict;
my $acroformdict          = PDF::API2::Basic::PDF::Dict->new();
$acroformdict->{Fields}   = PDFArray @formarray;
$acroformdict->{SigFlags} = PDFNum(3);
$acroformdict             = $p->new_obj($acroformdict);

$pdf->{catalog}->{'AcroForm'} = $acroformdict;
$pdf->{pdf}->out_obj($pdf->{catalog});


$pdf->saveas($tempfilename);
print "added AcroForm: $input_filename --> $tempfilename";
```

I am getting warning as below :

```
Usage: POSIX::strftime(fmt, sec, min, hour, mday, mon, year, wday = -1, yday = -1, isdst = -1) at signature.pl line 29
```

I used the code from https://mschuette.name/files/pdfsign.pl and https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1171455

Can anyone please help? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In list context, [`localtime`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/localtime.html) returns a list of 9 elements. However,

> In scalar context, localtime returns the ctime(3) value:

If you print `$timestamp`, you will get something like:

```
Tue Sep 10 15:37:22 2019
```

[`strftime`](https://perldoc.perl.org/POSIX.html#strftime), as your error message says (and as the documentation shows) expects 7 parameters. You should therefore pass it what `localtime` returns in list context rather than in scalar context. That is, use:

```
my @localtime  = localtime;
my $tz         = POSIX::strftime("%z", @localtime);
$tz            =~ s/([\+\-])(\d\d)(\d\d)/$1$2'$3'/;
my $timestring = POSIX::strftime("D:%Y%m%d%H%M%S$tz", @localtime);
```

---

For a small example reproducing what I'm talking about in my answer:

```
my $time = localtime;
say strftime "%Y", $time;
```

Will crash, whereas

```
my @time = localtime;
say strftime "%Y", @time;
```

Will work fine.

Comment: There's no need to put localtime into an array, it already defaults to returning an array, so it can be used directly. The usage errors I found to come from having mistakingly used Time::localtime instead of the native builtin. strftime "%Y", localtime; is all you need.

Comment: @lizardx In the first snippet, the result of localtime is used twice; might as well put it in an array instead of calling localtime twice, but it doesn't change much. In the second/third snippet, I'm demonstrating that putting the result of localtime in a scalar doesn't work with strftime, hence the array once again. Moreover, localtime does not "defaults to returning an array" : il returns a list in list context and a scalar in scalar context. When used as argument to strftime, it's a list context, and using an intermediate array is indeed not needed.

Comment: Keep in mind that this an answer is not a tutorial on how to use strftime and localtime: it's an _answer_ to a OP's question, aiming at showing him what it did wrong and how localtime is working.

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer is to call localtime in list context, but an alternative is to use the core [Time::Piece](https://perldoc.pl/Time::Piece) module, which provides a `localtime` function that returns an object with a `strftime` method.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Piece;

my $timepiece = localtime;
my $tz = $timepiece->strftime("%z"); #etc
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are just getting a date and time stamp for something. So here's the code I use for the current date and time in a special format:

```
###########################################################################
# July 2014
# Usage: $ts=getfulldatetime();
# Return current date and time in format: YYMMDD-hhmmss. Used on filenames.
sub getfulldatetime
{

my(@a,@b,$i,$j,$procname,$s,$t);
my($day,$mo,$sec,$year,$hr,$min);

$procname="getfulldatetime";
@a=localtime();
$day=sprintf("%02d",$a[3]);
$mo=sprintf("%02d",$a[4]+1); # Month is 0-11.

($sec,$min,$hr,$day, $mo, $year) = (localtime)[0,1,2,3,4,5];
$year=sprintf("%04d",$year);
$mo = sprintf '%02d', $mo+1;
$day   = sprintf '%02d', $day;
$s= ($year+1900).$mo.$day;
$s.="-".sprintf("%02d",$hr).sprintf("%02d",$min).sprintf("%02d",$sec);

return $s; # getfulldatetime
}
```

Remove whatever parts you don't need. This should not need any special `use` statements, it's pretty generic.

Comment: `use strict; use warnings;` please (`$min` is undeclared). Also, it's much easier to read if you indent your code. Finally, I don't see why your function is better than using `strftime` (you're computing pretty much the same thing as `strftime "%Y%m%d-%H%M%S", localtime`).

Comment: @Dada thanks. I fixed the lack of declaration of $min. This is designed to go into a library file like `util.pl` and `require`d into the main program. The main program should have `use strict; use warnings;`.

Comment: I don't blame you for not including strict/warnings in the snippet, but rather for not using it at all (since you forgot the declaration of $min). (You should still use strict/warnings in your libraries, and not only in the main)

Comment: @Dada Does the use strict/warnings have scope? So the use strict/warnings in my main program will not find the problems in my library? I guess it does have scope since my library never complained.

Comment: use strict/warnings have a scope indeed. But that shouldn't even come into consideration: you want to spot errors as soon as possible. You don't want to load 50 libraries in your main and get 3000 warnings.

Comment: (and seriously, `strftime` is much shorter, easier to read, and easier to maintain.. Want to change the format? easy, just change the format string. Want to add a separator? easy, just add a separator in the format string...)

Comment: Please do not recommend requiring Perl 4-style "library files".